# Serilog access original object in LogEvent that was passed to logging statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serilog

I am using Serilog in Unity3D.
I have a simple sink that writes Serilog logging statements to `Debug.LogFormat` of Unity:

```
public class UnityLogEventSink : ILogEventSink
{
    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        // QUESTION: How to pass a UnityEngine.Object to Serilog logging statement such that it is available here?
        UnityEngine.Object contextObject = null;
            
        using (StringWriter stringBuffer = new StringWriter())
        {
            GetTextFormatter().Format(logEvent, stringBuffer);
            LogType logType = GetUnityLogType(logEvent);
            string logString = stringBuffer.ToString().Trim();
            Debug.LogFormat(logType, LogOption.NoStacktrace, contextObject, logString);
        }
    }
    
    // GetTextFormatter, GetUnityLogType etc. are defined here ...
}
```

Now I want to pass a GameObject to the Serilog logging statement, such that I can access this GameObject in my sink. (Calling `Debug.LogFormat` with a GameObject will highlight the object in the Unity Editor when the log message is clicked. I want that.)

```
// Example what I have in mind (not working):
logger.ForContext("unityObject", gameObject).Information("This is an info with context");
```

I tried to wrap the GameObject in a ScalarValue, and a custom LogEventPropertyValue, but the GameObject is still converted to a string (happens in Serilog's PropertyValueConverter.cs).

I need the original GameObject instance for Debug.LogFormat.
Is there a way to preserve the GameObject reference so I can use it in my sink?

As a workaround, I could store the reference in a static map and log a string property with the key for the map. This way I could fetch the instance from that map later in the sink. But this is working around Serilog.
Is there a better solution that utilizes Serilog?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: And well since this happens somewhere deep inside that library you are using there ... It doesn't look like it is possible at all ... your input `object value` is converted to a `string` in various points .. doesn't seem like that library provides the reference afterwards...

Comment: (Aside: This couldn't be further from an unclear question IMO)

Comment: I re-phrased some parts and added code example. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick answered this very question for me in https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1124

```
public class ScalarValueEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    protected readonly LogEventProperty _prop;

    public ScalarValueEnricher(string name, object value)
    {
        _prop = new LogEventProperty(name, new ScalarValue(value));
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent evt, ILogEventPropertyFactory _) =>
         evt.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_prop);
}
```

([Here it is in context, in F#](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/master/src/Equinox.EventStore/EventStore.fs#L46))

Could also create a Unity specific subclass:

```
public class UnityObjectEnricher : ScalarValueEnricher
{
    public static readonly string unityObjectPropertyName = "unityObject";
    public UnityObjectEnricher(UnityEngine.Object value)
        : base(unityObjectPropertyName, value)
    {
    }
}
```

---

This property can then be accessed in the sink:

```
private UnityEngine.Object GetUnityEngineContextObject(LogEvent logEvent)
{
    if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(UnityObjectEnricher.unityObjectPropertyName, out LogEventPropertyValue logEventPropertyValue))
    {
        if (logEventPropertyValue is ScalarValue scalarValue)
            return scalarValue.Value as UnityEngine.Object;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Use it like:

```
// Note: using LogContext requires Serilog configuration ".Enrich.FromLogContext()"
using (LogContext.Push(new UnityObjectEnricher(gameObject)))
{
    logger.Information("This is an info with context");
}
```

Or:

```
logger.ForContext(new UnityObjectEnricher(gameObject)).Information("This is another info with context");
```

Comment: Thanks, ScalarValueEnricher was what I needed! I extended your answer with my new Unity specific subclass.